# Using Queues in Multi-Thread Python, Passing the queue to a subfunction as reference

Tags: python, multithreading

I am about to start on an endevour with python. The goal is to multithread different tasks and use queues to communicate between tasks. For the sake of clarity I would like to be able to pass a queue to a sub-function, thus sending information to the queue from there. So something similar like so:

```
from queue import Queue
from threading import Thread
import copy

# Object that signals shutdown
_sentinel = object()

# increment function
def increment(i, out_q):
    i += 1
    print(i)
    out_q.put(i)
    return

# A thread that produces data
def producer(out_q):
    i = 0
    while True:
        # Produce some data
        increment( i , out_q)

        if i > 5:
            out_q.put(_sentinel)
            break

# A thread that consumes data
def consumer(in_q):
    while True:
        # Get some data
        data = in_q.get()
        # Process the data

        # Check for termination
        if data is _sentinel:
            in_q.put(_sentinel)
            break


# Create the shared queue and launch both threads
q = Queue()
t1 = Thread(target=consumer, args=(q,))
t2 = Thread(target=producer, args=(q,))
t1.start()
t2.start()

# Wait for all produced items to be consumed
q.join()
```

Currently the output is a row of 0's, where I would like it to be the numbers 1 to 6. I have read the difficulty of passing references in python, but would like to clarify if this is just not possible in python or am I looking at this issue wrongly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem has nothing to do with the way the queues are passed; you're doing that right. The issue is actually related to how you're trying to increment `i`. Because variable in python [are passed by assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986006/how-do-i-pass-a-variable-by-reference), you have to actually return the incremented value of `i` back to the caller for the change you made inside `increment` to have any effect. Otherwise, you just rebind the local variable `i` inside of `increment`, and then `i` gets thrown away when `increment` completes.

You can also simplify your consume method a bit by using the `iter` built-in function, along with a `for` loop, to consume from the queue until `_sentinel` is reached, rather than a `while True` loop:

```
from queue import Queue
from threading import Thread
import copy

# Object that signals shutdown
_sentinel = object()

# increment function
def increment(i):
    i += 1
    return i

# A thread that produces data
def producer(out_q):
    i = 0
    while True:
        # Produce some data
        i = increment( i )
        print(i)
        out_q.put(i)
        if i > 5:
            out_q.put(_sentinel)
            break

# A thread that consumes data
def consumer(in_q):
    for data in iter(in_q.get, _sentinel):
        # Process the data
        pass


# Create the shared queue and launch both threads
q = Queue()
t1 = Thread(target=consumer, args=(q,))
t2 = Thread(target=producer, args=(q,))
t1.start()
t2.start()
```

Output:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
```